# Getting the columns of a pandas series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas.core.series as such:

```
140228202800    25
130422174258     5
131213194708     3
130726171426     1
```

I would like to get the first column and second column separately

Column 1:

```
140228202800
130422174258
131213194708
130726171426
```

Column 2:

```
25
5
3
1
```

I tried the following but no luck.

```
my_series.iloc[:,0]
my_series.loc[:,0]
my_series[:,0]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first "column" is the index you can get it using `s.index` or `s.index.to_list()` to get obtain it as a list.

To get the series values as a list use `s.to_list` and in order to get it as a numpy array use `s.values`.